# How to save "marker.getId()" to SQlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps

i am trying to save the extra data that goes with my marker to SQlite database.  So the problem i am facing is that the app crashes with this error:

```
12-22 09:12:04.096: E/SQLiteLog(17668): (1) no such column: img
12-22 09:12:04.106: W/dalvikvm(17668): threadid=23: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41816da0)
12-22 09:12:04.106: D/AbsListView(17668): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
12-22 09:12:04.106: D/AbsListView(17668): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-22 09:12:04.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17668): FATAL EXCEPTION: ModernAsyncTask #1
12-22 09:12:04.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17668): Process: com.example.mainapp, PID: 17668
12-22 09:12:04.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17668): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-22 09:12:04.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17668):    at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$3.done(ModernAsyncTask.java:137)
12-22 09:12:04.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17668):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
12-22 09:12:04.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17668):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
12-22 09:12:04.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17668):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
12-22 09:12:04.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17668):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-22 09:12:04.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17668):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-22 09:12:04.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17668):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-22 09:12:04.106: E/AndroidRuntime(17668): Caused by:  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: img (code 1): , while compiling:  SELECT _id, lat, lng, zom, img FROM locations
```

Now i have placed a column in my `LocationsDB.java` class:

```
/** Database name */
private static String DBNAME = "locationmarkersqlite";
private static int VERSION = 1;
public static final String FIELD_ROW_ID = "_id";
public static final String FIELD_LAT = "lat";
public static final String FIELD_LNG = "lng";
public static final String FIELD_ZOOM = "zom";
public static final String FIELD_IMAGE = "img"; // This is the new field
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "locations";
```

And then

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql =     "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " +
    FIELD_ROW_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement , " +
    FIELD_LNG + " double , " +
    FIELD_LAT + " double , " +
    FIELD_ZOOM + " text " +
    FIELD_IMAGE + "img" + //this line here added
    " ) ";
    db.execSQL(sql);
}
```

As well as here:

```
public Cursor getAllLocations(){
    return mDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { FIELD_ROW_ID,  FIELD_LAT , FIELD_LNG, FIELD_ZOOM, FIELD_IMAGE } , null, null, null, null, null, null); //FIELD_IMAGE added and null at the end
```

Then in my MainActivity class i added:

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_LAT, point.latitude );
contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_LNG, point.longitude);
contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_IMAGE, markerId + bitmap); //this line here added
contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_ZOOM, googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom);
```

Just to add i am using `HashMap` to get the image displayed for that specific marker

```
private Map<String, Bitmap> myMarkersHash;
private String markerId;

....

myMarkersHash = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();

....

Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(thePoint));
markerId = marker.getId();

....

Bitmap bitmap = myMarkersHash.get(marker.getId());
markerIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Then in `OnLoadFinished`:

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {
int locationCount = 0;
 double lat=0;
 double lng=0;
 float zoom=0;
 float img=0; //This Line here added
 locationCount = arg1.getCount();
 arg1.moveToFirst();

 for(int i=0;i<locationCount;i++){

 lat = arg1.getDouble(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_LAT));
 lng = arg1.getDouble(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_LNG));
 zoom = arg1.getFloat(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_ZOOM));
 img = arg1.getFloat(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_IMAGE)); //This line here added
 thePoint = new LatLng(lat, lng);
 drawMarker(thePoint);
 arg1.moveToNext();
 }

 if(locationCount>0){
 googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(lat,lng)));
 googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(zoom));
 bitmap = myMarkersHash.get(img); //This line here added
  }
}
```

What am i doing wrong here?  I have posted a similar question yesterday, but have decided to ask a new one with the code I have added instead of just no code for someone to try and figure out what i am trying to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you must correct how you create the database. The img field doesn't exists, and you are not creating a valid database field (img is not a type). Fix your database creation:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql =     "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " +
    FIELD_ROW_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement , " +
    FIELD_LNG + " double , " +
    FIELD_LAT + " double , " +
    FIELD_ZOOM + " text, " +   //Here forget a comma
    FIELD_IMAGE + " text" + //Here forget a space and you had put bad sqlite type, now text
    " ) ";
    db.execSQL(sql);
}
```

And finally, you must uninstall and reinstall app.

Comment: Cool thanks,  Really embarrassed now :-)  Also am i saving the image for that marker correctly?

Comment: You must use two fields: marker_id (text or number) and img(text referenced path or blob if binary on database)

Comment: Okay, but i am not sure how to do that?  its my first time using SQlite.  Could you possibly please show me how?

Comment: Add FIELD_MARKER_ID and FIELD_IMAGE. In FIELD_MARKER_ID save id marker and in FIELD_IMAGE the image.

Comment: Okay have done that but the image i am trying to save is `bitmap` so i get and error when writing the `contentValues` the error is `The method put(String, String) in the type ContentValues is not applicable for the arguments (String, Bitmap)`

Comment: This is another question

Comment: Okay, i have posted a new question,  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599116/how-can-i-save-the-markerid-and-image-in-sqlite-database)  like i said this is my firstime doing SQLite and there isn't much on explaining how to add marker id's with images to SQlite.

Answer (score 1):

You forget `, (comma)` after `FIELD_ZOOM + " text " +`

**Corrected:**

```
    String sql =     "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " +
    FIELD_ROW_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement , " +
    FIELD_LNG + " double , " +
    FIELD_LAT + " double , " +
    FIELD_ZOOM + " text, " +
    FIELD_IMAGE + "img" + //this line here added
    " ) ";
```

and if you recently added this Column then you must uninstall your app and install again a fresh built apk.